# HERE matrix routing testing url with apiKey

Tags: here-api

I am migrating my appCode and appId to apiKey. But I can't find the testing URL. I am currenlty using matrix.route.cit.api.here.com which doesn't fit with the new apiKey.
Does someone have a valid URL ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix routing production endpoint is at:

```
https://matrix.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.{format}
```

The testing one is at:

```
https://matrix.route.sit.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.{format}
```

Where format is either *json* or *xml*.

Comment: Thank you for @Michael. Unluckily I need to generate a valid apiKey for the testing URL and I can't figure out where I can have a valid api-key for the testing environement.

Comment: As far as I know, api keys generated in the developer project are not tied to a specific environment. In my case, the api key works indistinctly for both the production or testing environment.

Comment: For reference, I used this [request](https://matrix.route.sit.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?start0=52.5139%2C13.3576&start1=52.5214%2C13.4155&start2=52.5253%2C13.3693&destination0=52.5411%2C13.2127&destination1=52.5163%2C13.3780&destination2=52.4920%2C13.2849&destination3=52.4987%2C13.5228&destination4=52.5547%2C13.4578&mode=fastest%3Bcar&apiKey={{apiKey}}) that can be pasted in Postman, providing you have your _apiKey_ as variable there. Same api key works also with the production endpoint.

Comment: I am wondering why my api-key doesn't work on the test environement. I can't see any doc or reference on Here documentation.

Comment: Does your api key work with the exact same request in production, i.e. if you only remove `.sit` from the endpoint?

Comment: Do you mind adding the request you're trying, with all parameters but the api key? Are you firing the request from a script or from a rest client?

Comment: I am just trying a GET request using postman. Here is the full URL : https://matrix.route.sit.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?start2=50.13046,8.5732&start3=50.17979,8.51766&start4=50.15778,8.55425&destination0=50.16164,8.53413&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&matrixAttributes=ix,su&summaryattributes=all&jsoncallback=onMatrixCalculated&apikey=TpbAsGkQe7MXdDlHqCBCXbm8UGg5AZHU_BUdNza-nfg&start0=50.14928,8.52773&start1=50.14136,8.559

Comment: I've tried all the possibilities (apiKey, apikey, ApiKey..) but none of them worked for me. did apiKey work for you ?.

Answer (score 1):

Update : There was an issue identified with Matrix Routing API where some valid ApiKeys were being rejected, this should now be fixed.

You can test ApiKey with the following matrix routing API request-

```
https://matrix.route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?start2=50.13046,8.5732&start3=50.17979,8.51766&start4=50.15778,8.55425&destination0=50.16164,8.53413&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&matrixAttributes=ix,su&summaryattributes=all&jsoncallback=onMatrixCalculated&apikey={}&start0=50.14928,8.52773&start1=50.14136,8.559
```

for more details please check this documentation
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/request-matrix-of-routes.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I am looking for an URL to use the testing environement (equivalent to matrix.route.cit.api.here.com but supporting api-key) instead of production environement.

Comment: Check the new request for testing environment.

Comment: Hello again. I am wondering where I can genetate a valid api key for the testing environement. I generated one using the developper portal and the API says that the apikey is not valid.  thank you in advance for your asnwer.

Comment: You can use the one which you have generated on developer portal.

Comment: unfortunately using the api-key on the developper portal, the query doesn't work. Here is the API response : {
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "error_description": "ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."
}

Comment: Will you try to generate a new key and test this.

Comment: Yes. I did but it doesn't work. Still getting yhe same same error (401 Unauthorized) : {
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "error_description": "ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."
}