# here.com api key failing for calculate matrix

Tags: here-api

I'm using the here.com api to calculate a matrix, using a valid apiKey but getting the error message "ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found." However the apiKey worked until yesterday, is working for routing (as opposed to matrices) and I'm well below Freemium limits.

Using Here.coms example pages, the routing examples work and the matrix ones don't

**Car route from A to B**
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing/route-from-a-to-b

Putting in my api key works

**Many to many matrix routing**
https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/routing/many-to-many-matrix-routing

Putting in my api key gives the error '{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."}'

Even with the api keys that the page loads with, the matrix examples are getting no response whereas the routing examples work.

The website directs freemium users here for support so hoping you guys can help. Seems like it might be a temporary glitch?

Comment: Are you still having the issue? Can you share your complete code, minus the key if you want?

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue, some time I get the error described above. The error is sporadic but occurs with the same valid request that gets good result or sometime error of invalid key. I made some tests with Postman and I confirm this beheivoir. This happen with calculatematrix service and also with geocoder service.

Comment: Hi Raymond. Its now working thanks. The easiest way to test is with the code that the here.com example pages generate. In fact when the issue is happening, the example page doesn't seem to load properly, as in the Response section stays blank, so this may be a quick way to test the service. I agree with Pasquale the error is sporadic (and fingers crossed is gone)

Comment: Hi, for all the day until more or less 1 hour ago the services was responding good, but now gets more 401 with the same request and the same apiKey used this morning.

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like it may have been this status issue, https://status.here.com/status?id=status_history_details&sys_id=469f34711b264090cb5d8557cc4bcbf3, which is now marked as resolved. You can see our general status here, https://status.here.com/status. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Raymond that's useful. Upvoted it but not marked as the answer as it may also have been this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834825/11196018